# Unsupported version 0 of Verneed record and library loading errors

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gcc, ubuntu-16.04

Ever since I updated my Ubuntu 16.04 I am getting the following error when using **GCC** to compile a C code.

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/cc1: error while loading shared libraries: 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/cc1: unsupported version 0 of Verneed record
```

Just to inform while updating my internet connection was lost so i retried to update it but now i am getting these error when using **GCC** to compile a C code. So it would be great if someone helps me to figure out this error.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: [Bug 203311 - X server fails to start - unsupported version 0 of Verneed record](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=203311), [error while loading shared libraries: ./a.out: unsupported version 0 of Verneed record](http://lists2.linuxjournal.com/pipermail/linux-list/2005-January/022856.html), and friends.